# How to Build Deployment Package for Web App without full drive path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msdeploy, webdeploy

When right click on an ASP.NET Web Application and select "Build Deployment Package", I don't want it to create a .zip with the full path. I want the output to be the same no matter where it is built. Is this possible.

For example, if I create an Empty Web Application from the template, it will creates this zip
C:\Users\taggartc\tmp\EmptyWebApp\obj\Debug\Package\EmptyWebApp.zip

The zip has this structure:
Content\c_C\users\taggartc\tmp\EmptyWebApp\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\EmptyWebApp.dll

Is there any way to get rid of the path and have it be something like:
Content\bin\EmptyWebApp.dll

Comment: Why do you care about the layout?

Comment: I want the output to be the same no matter which developer builds it. Ideally, I want the checksum of the built .zip to be the same if a developer builds it, no matter what directory they put the source code in.

Comment: But why does it matter? It won't have the same timestamps; dlls inside will also have diff timestamps. It wouldn't be identical even if built on the same machine five minutes later.

Comment: Why does it put the full paths in the .zip? If I want to compare two different web packages for differences, doesn't it make it more difficult? I guess, I can strip the prefix up to "PackageTmp", but still.

Comment: If you want to compare two web packages, use the msdeploy command line. At worst, deploy one to a dummy site, then do a sync -whatif of the second. You may even be able to compare the two, possibly using sync -whatif. You'll never compare two builds, even if there were no packages involved at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no available option to use a relative path from within the zip archive.